# Running Advanced APIs As Other Users onOpen Somehow

Tags: google-apps-script, documentation

I am making a script that adds a subscription to PewDiePie when you open it. I have it partially working. It works when I open it, but I don't think it works as other users, as I expected. Are there any ideas on how to do make it work when run as others? Here's my code:

```
`function onOpen() {
  isEdited()
}
function isEdited() {

      var MyDoc = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument().getBody();
      var Text = MyDoc.editAsText().getText();
      var DocLen= Text.length;
      if(DocLen!= PropertiesService.getDocumentProperties().getProperty('DocLen'))
      {
        addSubscription();  
        PropertiesService.getDocumentProperties().setProperty('DocLen', DocLen)
      }    
    }
function addSubscription() {
  var channelId = 'UC-lHJZR3Gqxm24_Vd_AJ5Yw';
  var resource = {
    snippet: {
      resourceId: {
        kind: 'youtube#channel',
        channelId: channelId
      }
    }
  };`
```

I actually have an idea that might work, but I don't know how to do it and I can't find it anywhere. My idea is to make it create an installable trigger onOpen as the user who opened it. So yeah. 
Something I should address: The isEdited thing is just something I got from the Internet. It gets the job done, but onOpen didn't seem to work for whatever reason. 
thanks!

Comment: You should probably rephrase your issue and explain better what you want to achieve, for instance, why do you need the code to run in onOpen? Also, it might help to include the code you are using.

Comment: I realized how badly written that was and I completely rewrote it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I am making a script that adds a subscription to PewDiePie when you open it.

I hope you are getting consent from the user before you add the subscription

> create an installable trigger onOpen as the user who opened it

You cannot create an installable trigger the way you want it. Users can create their own installable triggers but user X cannot create an installable trigger for user Y.

Documentation for installable triggers @ https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable#restrictions

---

What I would do if I wanted to implement something like this is this:

- create a web app with google apps script to create the subscription and deploy it to execute it as the running user
- create a function that calls the web app
- create a menu and a menu item which a user should click to call the web app through the function

Documentation for web apps @ https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/web

Documentation on how to call web app @ https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/

Documentation for creating menus @ https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/menus

Comment: Hmm, I'll look into this! Thank you, Charalampos!